# how to fix "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list " error in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

The issue is occurring at FLIGHT table,

```
create table LOCATION (  
  airportCode   VARCHAR2(10) not null,  
  country       VARCHAR2(15) not null,  
  address       VARCHAR2(50) not null,  
  PRIMARY KEY(airportCode));

create table ROUTE (  
  routeID           VARCHAR2(10) not null,  
  airportCode       VARCHAR2(10) not null,  
  description       VARCHAR2(100) not null,  
  PRIMARY KEY(routeID, airportCode),
  FOREIGN KEY(airportCode) REFERENCES LOCATION(airportCode));

create table NEACC (  
  memberID          VARCHAR2(20),  
  flightGoldpoints  NUMBER,  
  PRIMARY KEY(memberID));

create table STAFF (  
  staffID           VARCHAR2(20) not null,  
  memberID          VARCHAR2(20) not null,
  name              VARCHAR2(20) not null,
  address           VARCHAR2(50) not null,
  email             VARCHAR2(30) not null,  
  phone             NUMBER not null,
  passportNum       NUMBER not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(staffID),
  FOREIGN KEY(memberID) REFERENCES NEACC(memberID));

create table FLIGHT (   
  flightID          VARCHAR2(20) not null,   
  routeID           VARCHAR2(20) not null,   
  staffID           VARCHAR2(20) not null, 
  captainOrFirstOfficer VARCHAR2(15) CHECK (captainOrFirstOfficer IN ('captain', 'first officer')) not null,
  estDepartDateTime VARCHAR2(20) not null,   
  actDepartDateTime VARCHAR2(20) not null,   
  actArriveDateTime VARCHAR2(20) not null, 
  avgSpeed          NUMBER not null, 
  avgHeight         NUMBER not null, 
  estDuration       NUMBER not null, 
  estFuel           NUMBER not null, 
  PRIMARY KEY(flightID, routeID), 
  FOREIGN KEY(routeID) REFERENCES ROUTE(routeID), 
  FOREIGN KEY(staffID) REFERENCES STAFF(staffID));
```

The error that I got is "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list". The foreign keys and primary keys are correctly referenced in the flight table but I didn't understand why this error is coming.

Answer (score 3):

The primary key in the `Route` table is:

```
PRIMARY KEY(routeID, airportCode),
```

The proper foreign key reference needs to reference both in order.  That would be:

```
FOREIGN KEY(routeID, airportCode) REFERENCES ROUTE(routeID, airportCode),
```

However, `FLIGHT` doesn't have an `airportCode`, so this will not work.

I am not sure what direction you want to take -- removing `airportCode` from the primary key or adding it to the `Flight` table.  But this is your problem.

Comment: but when I am trying to insert data into the flight, It is giving out the other error           `insert into FLIGHT values 
   ('flight1234', 'route1234', 'code1234', 'staff1234', 'captain', '24/4/2019', '24/4/2019', '25/4/2019', '180', '15000', '10', '50');` the error is "ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SQL_QKKKEDABZPGUNMQKZFLIVQIGO.SYS_C0014051958) violated - parent key not found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721"

Comment: @anu . . . This question is about your data model, which is not correct.  If -- after fixing that -- you have another question about inserting data, then you should ask that in a *question* not a *comment*.